# How to Isolate connected and fused characters from a text image using opencv

Tags: image, opencv, histogram

I have been developing an ocr system. I was able to segment out lines and words from the images fairly easily, but Iam completely stuck with character segmentation.How do i extract characters from these blocks. I have read many answers on forums but they have been applied on texts with enough spacing between two characters. I have tried histogram method to isolate characters from the words but the results are not satisfactory. 
My words look like this.[Image with characters touching eachother](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYJPR.jpg)
and [One more Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjmb0.jpg).
The thresholding process only adds to problem by fusing the characters further more. How can I segment these characters. 
This is what i have done so far: Function accepts a 2d list containing words  of size 500*500 pixels to be segmented:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
def character_detector(words):
    characters=[]
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
    for i in words:
        j=i
        l=[]
        for k in j:
            s=k
            f=k
            from cv2.ximgproc import THINNING_ZHANGSUEN
            s   =   cv2.ximgproc.thinning(k,s,thinningType=THINNING_ZHANGSUEN )
            s = cv2.dilate(s,kernel,iterations=3)
            k = cv2.threshold(k,75,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
            m = cv2.Canny(k,100,200)
            k=k-m
            i=0
            while i<5:
                m = cv2.Canny(k,100,200)
                k = k-m
                i+=1
            y_sum = cv2.reduce(k, 0, cv2.REDUCE_AVG)
            y_sum=y_sum[0]
            y_avg = sum(y_sum)//500
            hist =[]
            for i in range(0,500):
                if(y_sum[i]==0):
                    hist.append(False)
                else:
                    hist.append(True)
            j=1
            y_start=0
            y_end = 0
            y_coord=[]
            i=0
            while i<500:
                j=1
                if not(hist[i]):
                    i=i+1
                    continue
                else:
                    y_start = i
                    temp = i
                    j=0
                    while temp<500 and hist[temp]:
                        temp+=1
                        j+=1
                    i= i+j
                    y_end = y_start+j
                    y_coord.append((y_start,y_end))

            for i in range (0,len(y_coord),1):
                roi = f[0:500,y_coord[i][0]:y_coord[i][1]]
                cv2.imshow('thresh',roi)
                cv2.waitKey(0)
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```